# How can I reference System.Data.Odbc for dotnet core in my project?

Tags: odbc, .net-core

I have a project I'm deploying in Linux using dotnet core and I need to read a .mdb file. I want to use ODBC for it but even as I see that System.Data.Odbc has already been ported [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/15646) and that the documentation for the library is out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection?view=netcore-2.0) I can't find the nuget for it.

How can I download this library? Do I have to download the corefx project and build it by myself from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx)? When is this library going to be released? Is there another way to read my mdb file?

Comment: If I read the pull request that you refer to, it's still not in .Net Core 2.0 (although this pull request was merged). Looking at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7432 you still need to wait a bit (see last post).

Comment: Ok so, do you know how to package it by my self? I really do need this ODBC driver I don't need to be with EF I can use it using sql directly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
dotnet add package System.Data.Odbc --version 4.5.0-preview1-25915-02 --source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json
```